# Does Mandrill support i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm converting my email templates from basic `Action Mailer` views to `Mandrill` templates using the `mandrill-api` gem. I am wondering if `Mandrill` supports `i18n` or if I will have to provide all the translated sections myself server-side when I am making the request to the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mandrill templates do *not* support translations, but there are third party templating services like Customer.io and Sendwithus.com that support the i18n use case on top of Mandrill.

Translations are managed in app, and you specify a language via API.

They add an extra expense, but might be worth it if you're relying heavily on multi-language emails.

Comment: I reached out to them on Twitter, and they confirmed they don't support translations. I've decided to just provide the translated content from `Rails` and feed those in as merge vars.

Comment: Awesome. I've done that before and it's a great way to get started. If you have a large service or team though it can get messy.